# PostgreSQL query rows with least null value on columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, top-n

How can I query rows where the output would be the rows with least null value on the columns?

My data is:

```
ID         | col1     | col2      | col3      | col4     
-----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------
 1         | Null     |Null       | with value| with value
 2         |with value|Null       | with value| with value
 3         |with value|Null       | Null      | Null
```

where the result would be:

```
 ID         | col1     | col2      | col3      | col4     
 -----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------
  2         |with value|Null       | with value| with value
```

Because id 2 is the record with fewest null values.
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: what if there are more rows with equally low number of nulls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can:

1. Order rows by number of nulls (ascending)
2. Limit rows to 1 ( `LIMIT 1` )

Your code:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN col1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN col2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN col3 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN col4 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This will return the record with the *most* number of nulls, which is the opposite of what the OP asked for. Also, what happens if there's a tie for rows with the fewest null columns?

Comment: i think it should be the opposite if its null then 0 else 1 because OP wants less null value

Comment: @APC, thanks! I fixed it. About "the tie", I have no constraints to code it, OP don't talks about this.

Comment: Welcome buddy :)

Comment: Use `= ''` instead of `IS NULL` for empty string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one row, then you can do:

```
select t.*
from t
order by ( (col1 is null)::int + (col2 is null)::int +
           (col3 is null)::int + (col4 is null)::int
         ) asc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

If you want all such rows, I think I would do:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over 
                 (order by (col1 is null)::int + (col2 is null)::int +
                           (col3 is null)::int + (col4 is null)::int
                 ) as null_ranking
      from t
     ) t
where null_ranking = 1;
```